# Powershell convert columns of txt file to JSON format

Tags: json, powershell, parsing

I have the following output (in a file .txt)

```
Average:     CPU    %usr   %nice    %sys %iowait    %irq   %soft  %steal  %guest  %gnice   %idle
Average:     all    0.21    0.00    0.08    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.71
Average:       0    1.01    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   98.99
Average:       1    0.00    0.00    0.52    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.48
```

I need the number of CPU (1rst column) and the last one (%idle) to be parsed in a Json.

For example

```
[
  {
    "Num": "all",
    "Data": "99.71"
  },
  {
    "Num": "0",
    "Data": "98.99"
  },
  {
    "Num": "1",
    "Data": "99.48"
  }
]
```

but Instead I get the following output:

```
[
  "Num_all 99.71",
  "Num_0 98.99",
  "Num_1 99.48"
]
```

The Json is valid but unfortunately this is not the output expected.

My code:

```
$file = Join-Path $PSScriptRoot cpu.txt

#Create .temp file with the stats  
$cpu_stats = mpstat -P ALL 1 2 | grep Average > $file

#Print the first column (cpu num) and 11th (Average CPU)
$info_json = Get-Content $file | Select-object -skip 1| Foreach {"Num_$(($_ -split '\s+',12)[1,11])"} | ConvertTo-Json

#Print result (Json)
Write-Output $info_json
```

How can I get that with PowerShell?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to construct *objects* (`[pscustomobject]` instances) with `.Num` and `.Data` *properties* to get the JSON format you want:

```sh
Get-Content $file | 
  ForEach-Object {
    # Extract the column values of interest...
    $cpu, $idle = (-split $_)[1, -1]
    # ... and use them to construct and output a custom object.
    [pscustomobject] @{
      Num = $cpu
      Data = $idle
    }
  } | ConvertTo-Json
```

- I've used the *unary* form of the [`-split` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split) to split each line by nonempty runs of whitespace (while ignoring leading and trailing whitespace).
- Since the `%idle` column is the *last* one, it can be referred to with index `-1`.
- `$cpu, $idle = ...` is a *multi-assignment* that assigns the two array elements returned individually to the specified variables.
- `[pscustomobject] @{ ... }` is syntactic sugar for constructing a `[pscustomobject]` instance via a [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables) (`@{ ... }`).<sup>[1]</sup>

---

<sup>[1] Note that no separate hashtable is actually constructed when using this syntax. Also, unlike with true hashtables, the order of properties (keys) as specified is *preserved* in this case.</sup>